# Gaussian probability law

Tags: probability

for $X$ and $Y$, two independent random variables following the densities $f_X (x) = xe^{-\frac{x^2}{ 2}} 1_{]0,+\infty[} (x)$ and $f_Y (y) =  \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-y^2}} 1_{]-1,1[} (y)$ , I found that $(X,Y)$ follows

$ \frac{1}{\pi } e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{ 2}}1_{\mathbb{R}}(x)1_{\mathbb{R}_+^*}(y)$.

Is it the standard normal law, though we have a factor $\frac{1}{\pi} $ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ in the density?

Thank you!

Comment: I think in this question independence is not explicitly given, unless the author of the question forgot to mention it.  I think he needs to verify first if the random variables are independent, in that case follow that link.

Comment: Sorry just updated the question. Indeed X and Y are independent.
My main concern is to know if (X,Y) follow gaussian law though the factor is not $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: If I understand you correctly, $y$ has a different range than the standard normal range of $(-\infty, +\infty)$...

Comment: indeed, $y\in ]-1,1[$ and $x>0$

Comment: So if the range is not $(-\infty, +\infty)$, how can it be a normal variable?  (On a side note, what does $]-1, 1[$ mean?  I am familiar with $[-1, 1]$ being the closed interval between those numbers, but I am not familiar with the notation when the square brackets point "outward")

Comment: good point for the normal variable.
The notation ]-1,1[ means (-1,1) so the open interval without -1 and 1